# ImportError: Could not import settings 'company.foo.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named foo.settings

Tags: python, django, namespaces, setuptools

I was asked to split a big project into some reusable libraries (packages). So the idea was to do this:

- company-django-shared
- company-django-shared-dev
- company-python-shared
- company-python-shared-dev

These are installable with setuptools and namespaces:

- company
- company.packagename
- company.packagename.tests
- company.util
- etc...

All this works fine. I can start a shell and do any of the import i need. The problem arrives when I now want to use this in a django project. My settings are in:

- company.foo.settings

At this point, since setuptools installed some packages, when I try to

```
$ ./manage.py shell
```

I get the error::

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'company.foo.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named foo.settings
```

I really can't figure out how to use namespace within django apps. If I fire up a shell and do:

```
import company
company.__path__
```

The installed paths are found, but not the current directory. What am I missing?

***EDIT***

I would like to point out that the problem is Python cannot find any package under `company` because setuptools-installed packages define `company` as a namespace.

***EDIT 2***

Django is just unhappy with namespaces. It seems there are no viable solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found for now is the following:

- Do not use the `namespace_packages` parameter in setuptools.setup()

Instead, explicitly define "namespace" packages with this in the `__init__.py` file:

```
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
```

I have not done a lot of testings as to if this will work if I don't install my libraries in the same order, but at least, I am able to import my django settings (and everything else).

**EDIT**

This ended up not being a viable solutions because if librairies are uninstalled and reinstalled, they will delete more than they should, so ending up loosing modules.

I ended up using `namespace_packages` in `setuptools.setup()` and use a different first level "namespace" for the running django project.

**EDIT 2**

Scrap all this, this namespace thing seems to be a good idea, but ended up just being a nightmare with django. So i reverted everything back to non-namespace code. I'm not happy that I have to do this, but that's the price to work with django.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable to "company.foo.settings"?
From the Djanjo Documentation;  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#designating-the-settings

> When you use Django, you have to tell it which settings you’re using. Do this by using an environment variable, DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE.
>
> The value of DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE should be in Python path syntax, e.g. mysite.settings. Note that the settings module should be on the Python import search path.

EDIT:
Can you also add the following to the top of your manage.py file?
    import sys
    sys.path.append('/path/to/folder/containing/company')

EDIT2:
In response to your clarification, you can try relative imports:
http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision

```
from ..company import foo
```

Comment: Yes, that variable is set in the `manage.py` script. The problem is I cannot do:  `from company import foo`.

Answer (score 0):

try passing the location of the settings file directly to the command line.

`django-admin.py migrate --settings=mysite.settings` as seen in [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---settings)

Comment: The settings file itself is not the problem. Django (Python really) will not be able to find package `foo`, no matter how i pass it.